# How to convert json to columns and rows using oracle table function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table structure as below:

```
create table json_tab (id number constraint primary key,d_data clob(30000));

insert into json_tab values (1,'[{"a"=0,"b"=1},{"a"=1,"b"=2},{"a"=2,"b"=3}]');
insert into json_tab values (2,'[{"a"=0,"b"=1},{"a"=1,"b"=2},{"a"=2,"b"=3}]');
```

I want to write a query to fetch records as below format.

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |

Above is an example data. Real data is for JSON column more than 30000 bytes

Answer (score 5):

To begin with, your SQL code is not correct, neither for the create table, nor for the json document. Here's a corrected version:

```
drop table json_tab;
create table json_tab (id number  primary key,d_data clob check (d_data is json));
insert into json_tab values (1,'[{"a":0,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]');
insert into json_tab values (2,'[{"a":0,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]');

select j.id, t.a, t.b
from json_tab j, json_table (j.d_data columns (
        nested path '$[*]' COLUMNS(
            A NUMBER PATH '$.a',
            B number path '$.b'))) t;
```

And here's the output:

```
        ID          A          B
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0          1
         1          1          2
         1          2          3
         2          0          1
         2          1          2
         2          2          3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create your table as:

```sql
create table json_tab (
  id     NUMBER(8,0) CONSTRAINT json_tab__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  d_data CLOB        CONSTRAINT json_tab__d_data__json CHECK (d_data IS JSON)
);
```

Then your JSON data should use `"a":1` rather than `"a"=1` in the object's key-value pairs:

```sql
insert into json_tab ( id, d_data )
SELECT 1,'[{"a":0,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'[{"a":0,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can use a `JSON_TABLE`:

```sql
SELECT id,a,b
FROM   json_tab t
       CROSS JOIN
       JSON_TABLE(
         t.d_data,
         '$[*]'
         COLUMNS
           a NUMBER(5,0) PATH '$.a',
           b NUMBER(5,0) PATH '$.b'
       )
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID |  A |  B
> -: | -: | -:
>  1 |  0 |  1
>  1 |  1 |  2
>  1 |  2 |  3
>  2 |  0 |  1
>  2 |  1 |  2
>  2 |  2 |  3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2289caaa3d88efec0ef6f23833edd03)*