# parse string of json array using Oracle dbms_json

Tags: oracle, plsql

in oracle 19c plsql i have such string

```json
[{"Books":"book1","pages":"100"},{"Books":"book1","pages":"200"}]
```

i want to parse it using dbms_json to get table

| Books | pages |
| --- | --- |
| book1 | 100 |
| book2 | 200 |

how to do this? anyone can help?

Comment: No PL/SQL required: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59857542

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JSON_TABLE` function to take a JSON string and convert it to a table structure.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM JSON_TABLE ('[{"Books":"book1","pages":"100"},{"Books":"book1","pages":"200"}]',
                   '$[*]'
                   COLUMNS books PATH '$.Books', pages PATH '$.pages');
```